# Timeout was reached (Operation too slow. Less than 10 bytes/sec transferred the last 30 seconds)

Tags: rust, github-actions

I am tried to build the https://github.com/emk/rust-musl-builder project by myself with the fork repo https://github.com/jiangxiaoqiang/rust-musl-builder. when run this build process in github actions:

```
RUN env CARGO_HOME=/opt/rust/cargo cargo install -f cargo-deb &&     rm -rf /opt/rust/cargo/registry/
```

shows error:

```
#14 11.92 info: downloading component 'clippy'
#14 12.06 info: installing component 'clippy'
#14 12.48 info: downloading component 'rust-std' for 'x86_64-unknown-linux-musl'
#14 12.95 info: installing component 'rust-std' for 'x86_64-unknown-linux-musl'
#14 DONE 17.4s

#15 [11/15] ADD cargo-config.toml /opt/rust/cargo/config
#15 DONE 0.0s

#16 [12/15] RUN env CARGO_HOME=/opt/rust/cargo cargo install -f cargo-deb &&     rm -rf /opt/rust/cargo/registry/
#16 0.262     Updating crates.io index
#16 0.588  Downloading crates ...
#16 0.778   Downloaded cargo-deb v1.44.0
#16 0.839   Installing cargo-deb v1.44.0
#16 1.004     Updating crates.io index
#16 39.47 warning: spurious network error (3 tries remaining): [28] Timeout was reached (Operation too slow. Less than 10 bytes/sec transferred the last 30 seconds)
#16 77.61 warning: spurious network error (2 tries remaining): [28] Timeout was reached (Operation too slow. Less than 10 bytes/sec transferred the last 30 seconds)
#16 118.1 warning: spurious network error (1 tries remaining): [28] Timeout was reached (Operation too slow. Less than 10 bytes/sec transferred the last 30 seconds)
#16 161.6 error: failed to compile `cargo-deb v1.44.0`, intermediate artifacts can be found at `/tmp/cargo-installmscqoq`
#16 161.6 
#16 161.6 Caused by:
#16 161.6   failed to get `syn` as a dependency of package `serde_derive v1.0.165`
#16 161.6       ... which satisfies dependency `serde_derive = "=1.0.165"` of package `serde v1.0.165`
#16 161.6       ... which satisfies dependency `serde = "^1.0.152"` of package `cargo-deb v1.44.0`
#16 161.6 
#16 161.6 Caused by:
#16 161.6   failed to query replaced source registry `crates-io`
#16 161.6 
#16 161.6 Caused by:
#16 161.6   download of 3/s/syn failed
#16 161.6 
#16 161.6 Caused by:
#16 161.6   failed to download from `https://index.crates.io/3/s/syn`
#16 161.6 
#16 161.6 Caused by:
#16 161.6   [28] Timeout was reached (Operation too slow. Less than 10 bytes/sec transferred the last 30 seconds)
#16 ERROR: executor failed running [/bin/sh -c env CARGO_HOME=/opt/rust/cargo cargo install -f cargo-deb &&     rm -rf /opt/rust/cargo/registry/]: exit code: 101
------
 > [12/15] RUN env CARGO_HOME=/opt/rust/cargo cargo install -f cargo-deb &&     rm -rf /opt/rust/cargo/registry/:
161.6   failed to query replaced source registry `crates-io`
161.6 
161.6 Caused by:
161.6   download of 3/s/syn failed
161.6 
161.6 Caused by:
161.6   failed to download from `https://index.crates.io/3/s/syn`
161.6 
161.6 Caused by:
161.6   [28] Timeout was reached (Operation too slow. Less than 10 bytes/sec transferred the last 30 seconds)
------
ERROR: failed to solve: executor failed running [/bin/sh -c env CARGO_HOME=/opt/rust/cargo cargo install -f cargo-deb &&     rm -rf /opt/rust/cargo/registry/]: exit code: 101
Error: buildx call failed with: ERROR: failed to solve: executor failed running [/bin/sh -c env CARGO_HOME=/opt/rust/cargo cargo install -f cargo-deb &&     rm -rf /opt/rust/cargo/registry/]: exit code: 101
```

why the download speed so slow? what should I do to speed up the download process? this is the full docker file:

```
# Use Ubuntu 22.04 LTS as our base image.
FROM ubuntu:22.04

# The Rust toolchain to use when building our image.  Set by `hooks/build`.
ARG TOOLCHAIN=stable

# The OpenSSL version to use. Here is the place to check for new releases:
#
# - https://www.openssl.org/source/
#
# ALSO UPDATE hooks/build!
ARG OPENSSL_VERSION=1.1.1m

# Versions for other dependencies. Here are the places to check for new
# releases:
#
# - https://github.com/rust-lang/mdBook/releases
# - https://github.com/dylanowen/mdbook-graphviz/releases
# - https://github.com/EmbarkStudios/cargo-about/releases
# - https://github.com/rustsec/rustsec/releases
# - https://github.com/EmbarkStudios/cargo-deny/releases
# - http://zlib.net/
# - https://ftp.postgresql.org/pub/source/
#
# We're stuck on PostgreSQL 11 until we figure out
# https://github.com/emk/rust-musl-builder/issues.
ARG MDBOOK_VERSION=0.4.14
ARG MDBOOK_GRAPHVIZ_VERSION=0.1.3
ARG CARGO_ABOUT_VERSION=0.4.4
ARG CARGO_AUDIT_VERSION=0.16.0
ARG CARGO_DENY_VERSION=0.11.0
ARG ZLIB_VERSION=1.2.13
ARG POSTGRESQL_VERSION=11.14

# Make sure we have basic dev tools for building C libraries.  Our goal here is
# to support the musl-libc builds and Cargo builds needed for a large selection
# of the most popular crates.
#
# We also set up a `rust` user by default. This user has sudo privileges if you
# need to install any more software.
RUN apt-get update && \
    export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive && \
    apt-get install -yq \
        build-essential \
        cmake \
        curl \
        file \
        git \
        graphviz \
        musl-dev \
        musl-tools \
        libpq-dev \
        libsqlite-dev \
        libssl-dev \
        linux-libc-dev \
        pkgconf \
        sudo \
        unzip \
        xutils-dev \
        && \
    apt-get clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* && \
    useradd rust --user-group --create-home --shell /bin/bash --groups sudo

# - `mdbook` is the standard Rust tool for making searchable HTML manuals.
# - `mdbook-graphviz` allows using inline GraphViz drawing commands to add illustrations.
# - `cargo-about` generates a giant license file for all dependencies.
# - `cargo-audit` checks for security vulnerabilities. We include it for backwards compat.
# - `cargo-deny` does everything `cargo-audit` does, plus check licenses & many other things.
RUN curl -fLO https://github.com/rust-lang-nursery/mdBook/releases/download/v$MDBOOK_VERSION/mdbook-v$MDBOOK_VERSION-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu.tar.gz && \
    tar xf mdbook-v$MDBOOK_VERSION-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu.tar.gz && \
    mv mdbook /usr/local/bin/ && \
    rm -f mdbook-v$MDBOOK_VERSION-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu.tar.gz && \
    curl -fLO https://github.com/dylanowen/mdbook-graphviz/releases/download/v$MDBOOK_GRAPHVIZ_VERSION/mdbook-graphviz_v${MDBOOK_GRAPHVIZ_VERSION}_x86_64-unknown-linux-musl.zip && \
    unzip mdbook-graphviz_v${MDBOOK_GRAPHVIZ_VERSION}_x86_64-unknown-linux-musl.zip && \
    mv mdbook-graphviz /usr/local/bin/ && \
    rm -f mdbook-graphviz_v${MDBOOK_GRAPHVIZ_VERSION}_x86_64-unknown-linux-musl.zip && \
    curl -fLO https://github.com/EmbarkStudios/cargo-about/releases/download/$CARGO_ABOUT_VERSION/cargo-about-$CARGO_ABOUT_VERSION-x86_64-unknown-linux-musl.tar.gz && \
    tar xf cargo-about-$CARGO_ABOUT_VERSION-x86_64-unknown-linux-musl.tar.gz && \
    mv cargo-about-$CARGO_ABOUT_VERSION-x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/cargo-about /usr/local/bin/ && \
    rm -rf cargo-about-$CARGO_ABOUT_VERSION-x86_64-unknown-linux-musl.tar.gz cargo-about-$CARGO_ABOUT_VERSION-x86_64-unknown-linux-musl && \
    curl -fLO https://github.com/rustsec/rustsec/releases/download/cargo-audit%2Fv${CARGO_AUDIT_VERSION}/cargo-audit-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu-v${CARGO_AUDIT_VERSION}.tgz && \
    tar xf cargo-audit-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu-v${CARGO_AUDIT_VERSION}.tgz && \
    cp cargo-audit-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu-v${CARGO_AUDIT_VERSION}/cargo-audit /usr/local/bin/ && \
    rm -rf cargo-audit-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu-v${CARGO_AUDIT_VERSION}.tgz cargo-audit-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu-v${CARGO_AUDIT_VERSION} && \
    curl -fLO https://github.com/EmbarkStudios/cargo-deny/releases/download/$CARGO_DENY_VERSION/cargo-deny-$CARGO_DENY_VERSION-x86_64-unknown-linux-musl.tar.gz && \
    tar xf cargo-deny-$CARGO_DENY_VERSION-x86_64-unknown-linux-musl.tar.gz && \
    mv cargo-deny-$CARGO_DENY_VERSION-x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/cargo-deny /usr/local/bin/ && \
    rm -rf cargo-deny-$CARGO_DENY_VERSION-x86_64-unknown-linux-musl cargo-deny-$CARGO_DENY_VERSION-x86_64-unknown-linux-musl.tar.gz

# Static linking for C++ code
RUN ln -s "/usr/bin/g++" "/usr/bin/musl-g++"

# Build a static library version of OpenSSL using musl-libc.  This is needed by
# the popular Rust `hyper` crate.
#
# We point /usr/local/musl/include/linux at some Linux kernel headers (not
# necessarily the right ones) in an effort to compile OpenSSL 1.1's "engine"
# component. It's possible that this will cause bizarre and terrible things to
# happen. There may be "sanitized" header
RUN echo "Building OpenSSL" && \
    ls /usr/include/linux && \
    mkdir -p /usr/local/musl/include && \
    ln -s /usr/include/linux /usr/local/musl/include/linux && \
    ln -s /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/asm /usr/local/musl/include/asm && \
    ln -s /usr/include/asm-generic /usr/local/musl/include/asm-generic && \
    cd /tmp && \
    short_version="$(echo "$OPENSSL_VERSION" | sed s'/[a-z]$//' )" && \
    curl -fLO "https://www.openssl.org/source/openssl-$OPENSSL_VERSION.tar.gz" || \
        curl -fLO "https://www.openssl.org/source/old/$short_version/openssl-$OPENSSL_VERSION.tar.gz" && \
    tar xvzf "openssl-$OPENSSL_VERSION.tar.gz" && cd "openssl-$OPENSSL_VERSION" && \
    env CC=musl-gcc ./Configure no-shared no-zlib -fPIC --prefix=/usr/local/musl -DOPENSSL_NO_SECURE_MEMORY linux-x86_64 && \
    env C_INCLUDE_PATH=/usr/local/musl/include/ make depend && \
    env C_INCLUDE_PATH=/usr/local/musl/include/ make && \
    make install && \
    rm /usr/local/musl/include/linux /usr/local/musl/include/asm /usr/local/musl/include/asm-generic && \
    rm -r /tmp/*

RUN echo "Building zlib" && \
    cd /tmp && \
    curl -fLO "http://zlib.net/zlib-$ZLIB_VERSION.tar.gz" && \
    tar xzf "zlib-$ZLIB_VERSION.tar.gz" && cd "zlib-$ZLIB_VERSION" && \
    CC=musl-gcc ./configure --static --prefix=/usr/local/musl && \
    make && make install && \
    rm -r /tmp/*

RUN echo "Building libpq" && \
    cd /tmp && \
    curl -fLO "https://ftp.postgresql.org/pub/source/v$POSTGRESQL_VERSION/postgresql-$POSTGRESQL_VERSION.tar.gz" && \
    tar xzf "postgresql-$POSTGRESQL_VERSION.tar.gz" && cd "postgresql-$POSTGRESQL_VERSION" && \
    CC=musl-gcc CPPFLAGS=-I/usr/local/musl/include LDFLAGS=-L/usr/local/musl/lib ./configure --with-openssl --without-readline --prefix=/usr/local/musl && \
    cd src/interfaces/libpq && make all-static-lib && make install-lib-static && \
    cd ../../bin/pg_config && make && make install && \
    rm -r /tmp/*

# (Please feel free to submit pull requests for musl-libc builds of other C
# libraries needed by the most popular and common Rust crates, to avoid
# everybody needing to build them manually.)

# Install a `git credentials` helper for using GH_USER and GH_TOKEN to access
# private repositories if desired. We make sure this is configured for root,
# here, and for the `rust` user below.
ADD git-credential-ghtoken /usr/local/bin/ghtoken
RUN git config --global credential.https://github.com.helper ghtoken

# Set up our path with all our binary directories, including those for the
# musl-gcc toolchain and for our Rust toolchain.
#
# We use the instructions at https://github.com/rust-lang/rustup/issues/2383
# to install the rustup toolchain as root.
ENV RUSTUP_HOME=/opt/rust/rustup \
    PATH=/home/rust/.cargo/bin:/opt/rust/cargo/bin:/usr/local/musl/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin

# Install our Rust toolchain and the `musl` target.  We patch the
# command-line we pass to the installer so that it won't attempt to
# interact with the user or fool around with TTYs.  We also set the default
# `--target` to musl so that our users don't need to keep overriding it
# manually.
RUN curl https://sh.rustup.rs -sSf | \
    env CARGO_HOME=/opt/rust/cargo \
        sh -s -- -y --default-toolchain $TOOLCHAIN --profile minimal --no-modify-path && \
    env CARGO_HOME=/opt/rust/cargo \
        rustup component add rustfmt && \
    env CARGO_HOME=/opt/rust/cargo \
        rustup component add clippy && \
    env CARGO_HOME=/opt/rust/cargo \
        rustup target add x86_64-unknown-linux-musl
ADD cargo-config.toml /opt/rust/cargo/config

# Set up our environment variables so that we cross-compile using musl-libc by
# default.
ENV X86_64_UNKNOWN_LINUX_MUSL_OPENSSL_DIR=/usr/local/musl/ \
    X86_64_UNKNOWN_LINUX_MUSL_OPENSSL_STATIC=1 \
    PQ_LIB_STATIC_X86_64_UNKNOWN_LINUX_MUSL=1 \
    PG_CONFIG_X86_64_UNKNOWN_LINUX_GNU=/usr/bin/pg_config \
    PKG_CONFIG_ALLOW_CROSS=true \
    PKG_CONFIG_ALL_STATIC=true \
    LIBZ_SYS_STATIC=1 \
    TARGET=musl

# Install some useful Rust tools from source (as few as we can, because these
# slow down image builds). This will use the static linking toolchain, but that
# should be OK.
#
# - `cargo-deb` builds Debian packages.
RUN env CARGO_HOME=/opt/rust/cargo cargo install -f cargo-deb && \
    rm -rf /opt/rust/cargo/registry/

# Allow sudo without a password.
ADD sudoers /etc/sudoers.d/nopasswd

# Run all further code as user `rust`, create our working directories, install
# our config file, and set up our credential helper.
#
# You should be able to switch back to `USER root` from another `Dockerfile`
# using this image if you need to do so.
USER rust
RUN mkdir -p /home/rust/libs /home/rust/src /home/rust/.cargo && \
    ln -s /opt/rust/cargo/config /home/rust/.cargo/config && \
    git config --global credential.https://github.com.helper ghtoken

# Expect our source code to live in /home/rust/src.  We'll run the build as
# user `rust`, which will be uid 1000, gid 1000 outside the container.
WORKDIR /home/rust/src
```

Answer (score 0):

As documented on the repo:
You may be able to speed up build performance by adding the following `-v` commands to the `rust-musl-builder` alias:

```bash
-v cargo-git:/home/rust/.cargo/git
-v cargo-registry:/home/rust/.cargo/registry
-v target:/home/rust/src/target
```

You will also need to fix the permissions on the mounted volumes:

```bash
rust-musl-builder sudo chown -R rust:rust \
  /home/rust/.cargo/git /home/rust/.cargo/registry /home/rust/src/target
```